# has_many and belongs_to to same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, has-many, belongs-to

I have a video model and thumbnail model
1. Video can have many thumbnails and each thumbnail belongs to a video.
2. Each video has a special thumbnail called hero_thumbnail which need to be chosen from video's thumbnails

Problem:
When i go to edit my video and want to chose a thumbnail for this particular video from its own thumbnails, then i see all of the thumbnails(all available in table) loaded into the drop down.
Logically, it seems to be correct but i only want to display those thumbnails in the list that belongs_to this video.

Here is my associations. May be i am missing some association.

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :thumbnails
  belongs_to  :hero_thumbnail, foreign_key: 'hero_thumbnail_id', class_name: 'Thumbnail'
end

class Thumbnail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :video
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that you need to choose `has_one` instead of `belongs_to`.
Also the problem with all thumbnails in a list is in your controller or view.
Show your `def edit` from `videos_controller` and video's `edit.html.erb`.

Comment: @PeterTretyakov: Man, actually i am using activeadmin this is in the default edit/new form. Let me try out has_one.

Comment: Nopes, has_one removes the selection drop down from the form.

Comment: Can you show the form and videos_controller?

Comment: @PeterTretyakov: I am doing nothing in controller related to this. I am using default controller/views of active-admin.

Comment: Without building your app I can't be sure, but have you tried `has_one :hero_thumbnail ...`? I am not sure you can add that field just with associations. I think you need to write a migration and a little controller code for that.

Comment: I agree that more code will clarify the situation.  I'm especially interested in the form code.